# how to delete all rows in jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt, jpanel

*i have one problem to delete the all rows in my table ,i have one Jpanel which have jtable, when i select the row it will display the corresponding row   value ,and when  i click another button on same panel means it,will  reload the table,here is the problem, i got the exception*

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
        at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
        at Testsample$16.valueChanged(Testsample.java:1516)
```

*i almost use all methods to delete rows in table
now i use this method*

```
while (table.getRowCount() > 0) {
                    ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(0);
                }
```

*note :i use two panel for this sample application when all controlls are in same it's everything working fine, if i set the table in second panel means ,it throws above exception ,any idea how solve this problem*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception you are seeing is coming from the Swing Thread (AWT-EventQueue-0).  The exception is happening because the JTable is drawing itself (on the Swing Thread) at the same time that you are modifying the DefaultTableModel on some other thread.

Do not do that!  All changes to the table model must happen on the Swing Thread.

See [Last word in Swing Threads](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads3.html)

Use `EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {...});` or something similar.

Answer (score 6):

Try this code..

```
DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
dm.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
```

Comment: That can still lead to the exception he reported, unless that code is executed on the Swing event thread.

Answer (score 2):

This is my method:

```
DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
            int rc= model.getRowCount();
            for(int i = 0;i<rc;i++){
                model.removeRow(0);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code

```
dtm_vendor = new DefaultTableModel();
jTable_vendor.setModel(dtm_vendor);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!